# Bootstrap panels failing to display but navbar and footer work in Angular4 app?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-4

So I have an angular4 app I'm building with an `app.component.html` that looks like this:

```html
<app-nav></app-nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      TEST HEAD 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

The `nav.component.html` looks like this:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome!</a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="home" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        Home 
        <!--<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>-->
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="contact" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        Contact
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="https://twitter.com/dril" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="https://github.com/dril" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And a `footer.component.html` that looks like this:

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="text-muted">
      Footer
    </span>
  </div>
</footer>
```

As you can see, I'm using bootstrap and font-awesome to style everything, in addition to a global `styles.css` that looks like this:

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding-top: 5rem;
}
.starter-template {
  padding: 3rem 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The nav and footer components are styling correctly. However, the `panel` styles do not seem to be applying in the main `app.component.html` or anywhere else I'm testing panels.

What gives?

Comment: create a plunker to reproduce

Comment: where us the panel styles defined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged bootstrap 4. If you really use bootstrap 4, it's normal that panel class doesnt have a style because for bootstrap 4 you should use card to make a panel style : https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/

Should be:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    Quote
  </div>
  <div class="card-block">
    <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      <footer>Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite></footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```